# Http Request Timeouts on Azure Web Apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis

We have a collection of MVC 5 websites running on the Azure Cloud Hosting platform. We have several different versions of the environment with which these websites run (Development, Staging, Production), and we are experiencing a very difficult to troubleshoot issue. It seems that, intermittently, when a request is made to the production environment, the request will be rejected, or the file will be served slowly to the point of the server timing out and aborting the request. This only seems to occur in the production environment, and does not appear to happen in development or staging.

Given that our websites just recently started receiving traffic, the production environment is actually the lesser used in this case, so it is not a matter of the machine being out of resources. Also, we have the capability to monitor the resources of the machine through a web ui, and we do not see any issues here.

When configuring these systems, we do not have a ton of control over how they are set up. To that end, it's unlikely that there is a configuration difference between them, as they are setup (presumably) from an image, and configured through a web UI. The settings on these systems is the same between them as far as we can tell. To ensure its not an issue of configuration of the machine, we have mirrored the production environment by recreating it, and we're still experiencing the same issue.

The websites in our environments are secured via SSL certificates. In order to remove that as the potential culprit, we've turned SSL off on our production site and tested it. This didn't seem to fix the issue and we still got intermittent failed requests.

We thought it may have to do with Routing, and MVC handling the files, so we've attempted downloads of static files (Images, javascript files) as well as dynamic files (Views, bundled javascript), and we still get these failed requests. In our bundling configuration, we do not override the default RouteExistingFiles value, so MVC should not be handling the routing of static files (as I understand it, at least, please correct me if I'm wrong)

Our tests are run against the primary domain name on the account, and it doesn't appear that the issue is attributed to anything DNS related.

It doesn't seem to have anything to do with our database connections, as we do not hit our database when serving up static files, nor when we load our login page (which we tested against primarily)

We are really running short on ideas with regard to what might be causing this issue, and we were really hoping someone out there may have experienced a similar issue with the Azure Cloud platform? Alternatively, if anyone has any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the "Always On" feature, this can be done via the web app settings.

How Azure App Service works is that the site content is stored on a file server, and then the site is loaded by a web worker when it is active. If the site is idle it will be unloaded. When the new request comes in, the site will have to be reloaded, which may cause the slowdown you are experiencing. In addition, content may be ngen'd again, which would further contribute to the slowdown.

Documentation for configuring web apps is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/

Comment: We have tried the site with Always On turned on and off with the same results. In addition we have Azure Application Insights setup for these sites and availability checks turned on so requests are hitting the main page of the site every few minutes.